# Class not found exception in Omnifaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, omnifaces

I get this error when I try to use the omnifaces

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:591)

Please can anyone help me and tell me what is the problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

That means you are missing a jar in the classpath. Find the jar that contains `org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: how did you add the jar to classpath?

Comment: right click on the project then libraries then add jar/folder then I add it.

Comment: I am using netbeans 6.9.1 btw

Comment: You run it as a standalone desktop program or is running on a server?

Comment: locally on a local server? or as a main class?

Comment: it's a web project and on tomcat server locally

Comment: then adding the jar to the project classpath in the IDE will not help. If its a web project, put the jar under WEB-INF/lib folder, you can also copy the jar under the server lib folder.

Comment: I tried that already but it is still not working
I am really confused and don't know what is wrong with this !!